# HANA + Is it possible to create a local temp table with dynamic name (name including current time)?

Tags: hana

As we do in SQL, is it possible to pass variable on create statement as a table name in HANA?

I'm trying the below code but its throwing an error

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE temp_table()
    AS
    
    table_name nvarchar(255);
    
    BEGIN
    
    table_name := '#TMP_TABLE'+ CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    
        CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY COLUMN TABLE :table_name(
                SCENARIO varchar(64) NULL,
                SCENARIO_CY varchar(64) NULL,
                MONTH_NO numeric(4, 0) NULL
            );
    
    DROP TABLE :table_name;
    END;
```

Please help me to find out a solution.

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do? What would be the purpose of a table that cannot be referenced as it's name is unknown?

Comment: @JonasWilms Of course the name is known (it's :table_name). It just needs to be passed as a variable at query time. This is possible using Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @MathiasKemeter well if there is a variable holding a name, why can't that variable hold the table? To me the question sounds a lot like an XY problem, that's why I asked for clarification. In the actual usecase, there might actually a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Dynamic SQL](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/966714d37630404983e8f4e3708ae79c.html?locale=en-US). You will need to pass your SQL statement as a string to function [EXEC](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/8462312b31d04879b124acb6b0275247.html?locale=en-US) or [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/093c4fd307064f838cb582555c187b9e.html?locale=en-US). The timestamp dependent name can be assembled by string concatenation.

In your code above your are using '+' to do string concatenation:

```
table_name := '#TMP_TABLE'+ CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

IMHO this does not work on HANA. You should use a double pipe '||' instead:

```
table_name := '#TMP_TABLE' || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```